# Command not found: dev:watch

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

According to the [Karaf 3.0.3 user guide](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/developer-commands.html#Watch) there is the `dev:watch` command:

> The following command:
>
> ```
>   karaf@root> dev:watch *
> ```
>
> will monitore all bundles that have a location matching mvn:* and having '-SNAPSHOT' in their URL.

When I enter `dev:watch *`, I get this error:

```
Command not found: dev:watch
```

The command is still mentioned in some issues in the [3.0.0 change log](http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/download/karaf-3.0.0-release.html) but not in later versions. Has it been removed and is there an alternative command or any similar feature to update snapshot bundles?

It tried `bundle:watch *` but get following exception:

```
karaf@root()> Exception in thread "Thread-32" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/karaf/util/maven/Parser
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.internal.BundleWatcherImpl.getBundleExternalLocation(BundleWatcherImpl.java:195)
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.internal.BundleWatcherImpl.updateBundleIfNecessary(BundleWatcherImpl.java:144)
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.internal.BundleWatcherImpl.run(BundleWatcherImpl.java:100)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.karaf.util.maven.Parser not found by org.apache.karaf.bundle.core [31]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command was renamed to bundle:watch. See [developer commands](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/developer-commands.html)

Comment: Thanks, so I was on the right track. It seems like the user guide is a bit out of date though because that's the page I quoted. So `bundle:watch *` as I've tried is the correct command then? Do you have any idea why I get the exception?

Comment: Never mind, found the issue. It's a known bug (and already got fixed) : [KARAF-3283](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-3283)